# How do you properly hold your breath in Alien Isolation

Tags: alien-isolation

I have been trying to hold my breath in the Xbox One version of Alien Isolation. I can not seem to figure it out. Every time I try, the Alien discovers me and pulls me out of the locker (or wherever I'm hiding). So two questions: A) How do I actually do it (hold my breath) B) Is there some sort of visual indicator showing that I am holding my breath?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the Xbox One version, but the PC version using an Xbox 360 pad has you hold your breath by pressing and holding LT (left trigger).

HOWEVER, you also need to be leaning away from the door (down on the left control stick) or the Alien will see you.

After you've been holding your breath for a bit, the sides of the screen will start to flash red and you'll start slowly taking damage (I think).  At this point, you also start making a small amount of noise.  From experience, you will remain trying to hold your breath until you let go of both LT and the control stick... and hope the Alien hasn't heard you.

Answer (score 2):

I die most of the time. But I managed to survive twice.

It'll either prompt Push the LS (Left Stick: push down on the stick) or LT (Left Trigger) Button. Hitting either button before doesn't do anything.

For it to work I think you need to be in a neutral position (not already leaning back) when it prompts.

So when the text appears push one of the two button, then lean back. Hold it until the Alien is far enough then release. You'll see red flashes on your screen when holding your breath.

Comment: That's not in my AI on PS4! I just lean back when hostiles are searching outside.There're no prompts.

Answer (score 0):

On the xbone version you have to pull back on the left stick and hold the left trigger at the same time. Don't pull LT until the enemy is close.

You're fine at first, but the longer you hold your breath the more a dark red effect spreads in from the edges of the screen.

When you finally let go you'll make a quiet noise and see flecks on the edges of your vision.

Comment: I have tried this exact process numerous times to no avail. When the ailing interesting room I pull back on the left analog stick ( which is doe word thirds myselft) and I am not pressing down on said stick. When the alien approaches I then pull in the left trigger and hold it there but the alien always seems to detect and kill me. The entire time while doing so as far as I can tell there's no visual indications that I am holding my breath. This seems to be a bad game design decision as there's no indicator to understand that this control is actively being used.

Comment: @Mort - you don't do it until the Alien is quite close. You get a screen prompt to pull LT but on hard this lasts a fraction of a second. It doesn't work if the motion tracker is up (and the Alien can hear that anyway). Also note that locker hiding is very temporary - the Alien can smell you and will keep coming back to the room that you're in. If you can hide under a table or behind something that nearly always works better.